# how to use maven with osgi in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi

I'm new with maven and OSGi and **i want to use OSGi with maven**. At the beginning i search but i haven't find some article that fit my needs. SO i decided to ask here.

**I have understand that i have to use maven-bundle-plugin but i don't know how to use it on eclipse**. Please if you know how to integrate it on eclipse explain me it.

I have already downloaded the m2e integration from Eclipse's marketplace and i have installed it.

http://securesoftwaredev.com/2009/11/21/osgi-maven-eclipse/

I have also followed the steps of this tutorial but in my case doesn't appear the maven option on the context menu.

Comment: Are you talking about Eclipse IDE or Eclipse RCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to develop OSGi bundles or run OSGi container and get the bundles as maven dependencies, you might find this unfinished tutorial useful: http://cookbook.everit.org/

Please note that such tutorials get out-of-date easily as the tools are rapidly improved for OSGi. E.g.: The tutorial I mentioned will be reviewed soon if bnd-maven-plugin can be used instead of maven-bundle-plugin.

Comment: Thank you this tutorial help me to solve my problems!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit outdated. If you use a current eclipse then m2e is preinstalled (best use Luna, I got some problems with m2e and Mars). 
Then just create a new maven project or import an existing one. I use the maven bundle plugin in a normal maven build (not tycho). So do not use the eclipse plugin perspective.

See also the [Karaf Tutorials for complete examples](http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/02/15/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+1+-+Installation+and+First+application).